# RSpec let Scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

How is RSpec let scoping defined? I have a test that uses shared_examples and I think the let's are leaking. I thought this would work but I'm missing some understanding if anyone can explain why `foo` is only defined as `123` here.

```
# test.rb
RSpec.describe "Test" do
  let(:foo) { '123' }

  include_examples "when missing foo"
  include_examples "when foo is valid"
end


# shared_examples.rb
shared_examples "when missing foo" do
  let(:foo) { nil }

  it "expects foo to be nil" do
    expect(foo).to be_nil
  end
end

shared_examples "when foo is valid" do
  let(:foo) { 123 }

  it "expects foo to not be nil" do
    expect(foo).to eq(123)
  end
end
```

Test result:

```
Test
  expects foo to not be nil
  expects foo to be nil (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) Test expects foo to be nil
     Failure/Error: expect(foo).to be_nil
     
       expected: nil
            got: 123
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let` is a shorthand for a memoized method definition think

```
def foo
  @foo ||= '123'
end
```

`include_examples` just merges the `shared_examples` into the current context so your `foo` definition is being overwritten e.g. Your example this becomes:

```
RSpec.describe "Test" do
  let(:foo) {'123' }
  let(:foo) { nil }
  let(:foo) { 123 }

  it "expects foo to be nil" do
    expect(foo).to be_nil
  end

  it "expects foo to not be nil" do
    expect(foo).to eq(123)
  end
end
```

Which is why the test fails. If you were to reverse the order of the include examples you will note the other test would be the failing one.

That being said you can use `it_behaves_like` instead, which will create a nested context and your `foo` definitions will be isolated to that context:

```
RSpec.describe "Test" do
  let(:foo) { '123' }

  it_behaves_like "when missing foo"
  it_behaves_like "when foo is valid"
end
```

In this case your `foo` will be wrapped in its own context and both tests will pass.

This is further explained in the [RSpec Documentation for shared_examples](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples)

Answer (score 1):

`let` is not scoped to a shared example as its not an example group.

If you want to redefine `foo` per shared example you would do it like so:

```
RSpec.describe "Test" do
  let(:foo) { '123' }

  include_examples "when missing foo" do
    let(:foo) { nil }
  end
  include_examples "when foo is valid" do
    let(:foo) { 123 }
  end
end

# shared_examples.rb
shared_examples "when missing foo" do
  it "expects foo to be nil" do
    expect(foo).to be_nil
  end
end

shared_examples "when foo is valid" do
  it "expects foo to not be nil" do
    expect(foo).to eq(123)
  end
end
```

Or you would just define foo as a parameter instead of using let:

```
shared_examples "when missing foo" do |foo|
  it "expects foo to be nil" do
    expect(foo).to be_nil
  end
end
```

```
include_examples "when missing foo", foo: nil
```

Comment: Conceptually though I don't think you have understood how shared examples are supposted to be used. You're using it somewhat like a shared context when in reality the spec using the shared examples is the boss.

Comment: gotcha, thanks for the callout!